# Calling a C# DLL from Delphi, with array of byte parameter

Tags: c#, delphi

I call a dll "plcommpro.dll" for a specific operations on Access Controls
the following C# code is working perfect and retrieve data correctly in buffer

```
[DllImport("plcommpro.dll", EntryPoint = "GetDeviceData")]
public static extern int GetDeviceData(IntPtr h, ref byte buffer,
int buffersize, string tablename, string filename, string filter, string   
options);
```

Now, I need to to write same operation from Delphi, So I tried the following:

```
TGetDeviceData = Function(iDevID : NativeInt; buffer : Pbyte ; iSize :   
Integer; 
tablename, filename, strFilter, strOptions : PAnsiChar) : Int64;stdcall;
```

and I call the function as follows:

```
var
myBuffer : TBytes;
iRetLog : Integer;
bufferSize : Integer;
sConnect : TConnect;
GetDeviceData : TGetDeviceData;
dllHandle : THandle;
iDevID : Integer;
begin
      dllHandle := LoadLibrary('plcommpro.dll') ;
      if dllHandle <> 0 then
      begin
         @sConnect := GetProcAddress(dllHandle, 'Connect');
         if @sConnect <> Nil then
         begin
            strParams := PChar('protocol=TCP,ipaddress=' + grd_Machines.Cells[cl_Machine_IP, iLoop] + ',port=4370,timeout=2000,passwd=');
            iDevID := sConnect(strParams);
             strTableName := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(('user')));
             strDatas := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(''));
             strFileName := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(''));
             strFilter := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(''));
             strOptions := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(''));

             @GetDeviceData := GetProcAddress(dllHandle, 'GetDeviceData');
             if @GetDeviceData <> Nil then
             begin
                try
                  buffersize :=  1024*1024;
                  //bufferSize := MaxInt - 1;
                  SetLength(myBuffer,  1024*1024);
                  mem_AttLogs.Lines.Add('buffer Size : ' + IntToStr(buffersize) );
                  iRetLogs := GetDeviceData(iDevID, PByte(myBuffer[0]), buffersize, strTableName, strFileName, strFilter, strOptions);
                  if iRetLogs > 0 then
                  begin
                     ....
                     //Here: I need to read the returned values from the function; but it always fails
                  end
```

The code is modified to explain my case more clearly. Can you help?

Comment: The `var byte: PByte` is wrong (one level of indirection too many). First, `Byte` is an existing type, and while that is probably legal, I think you should name it e.g. `buffer` like in the C# assembly. But more importantly, you should get rid of the `var`. So make it: `buffer: PByte`. FWIW, the `AnsiString` is wrong too. Make it `PAnsiChar`.

Comment: Can you show us how you access your byte? This is a pointer to byte which usually references a byte array, but you seem to be referencing a single byte. Showing us the code that you use to try and get 'byte' will help. Notice also that in Delphi, byte is a data type, so different name might be helpful.

Comment: FWIW, is that correct? That looks as if it is importing from a non-.NET DLL into C#, hence the `DllImport` attribute. If that is the case, you should be using the `plcommpro.dll` directly. Perhaps there is even a C header for it.

Comment: True, I am using "plcommpro.dll" directly. The problem is, I can't get data from my Delphi Application, but I can get data from C# App.

Comment: Do you have a C header for the DLL? If so, show the C declaration of the same function. And the `PByte` should really not be a `var` parameter. Nor should the strings be translated to `AnsiString` (a Delphi-specific type, which does not exist in C or in C#). It should be `PAnsiChar`, which is a translation of `char *` in C. The .NET marshalling code will convert `char *` to a C# string, but that doesn't work in Delphi. Take a look at [my article](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html) about using DLLs.

Comment: That C# code is pretty bogus. Go back to the C header. Even so, your delphi conversion has very many mistakes.

Comment: I changed my Delphi Header as following:     
TGetDeviceData = Function(iDevID : NativeInt; myBuffer : PByte ; iSize : Cardinal; tablename, filename, strFilter, strOptions : PAnsiChar) : UInt64;stdcall;
and after calling the function, I need to parse my array so, I read  myBuffer as following :                     

LEncoding := NIL;
LOffset := TEncoding.GetBufferEncoding(myBuffer, LEncoding);
strReturn := LEncoding.GetString(myBuffer, LOffset, Length(myBuffer) - LOffset - 1);

Comment: I call the function as following 
iDev : Integer;
myBuffer : TBytes;
str... : PAnsiChar;
GetDeviceData(iDevID, @myBuffer[0] , buffersize, strTableName, strFileName, strFilter, strOptions)

Comment: Try this: `function GetDeviceData(h: THandle; buffer: PByte; buffersize: Integer; tablename, filename, filter, options: PAnsiChar): Integer; stdcall; external 'plcommpro.dll';`

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis
Please tell me if I can pass "array of byte" from Delphi to C# !!
and if not, what is the alternative and how to access the data back in delphi?
The function now always fails!

Comment: Are you passing to C#? If so, no you can't. `array of Byte` is a Delphi-specific type which is managed by the Delphi runtime.You can *use* one, and pass a pointer to its first element, as you do in your comment above. But be sure to do a `SetLength(myBuffer, ...)`first, because C# can't and won't do that for you.

Comment: But now I am confused. You seem to be using `plcommpro.dll`. Is that a .NET assembly? Or just a simple DLL? The fact C# must import from it using marshalling tells me it is a non-.NET DLL. Either way, you can't use Delphi-specific types. See [another article I wrote](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html) about "DLL do's and don'ts".

Comment: So again, what has C# to do with this? You are using a normal Windows DLL from a Windows application, you are not calling into C#. So why are you asking about passing to C#? But **edit your question** and show **exactly** how you declare and use the function, in other words, **add your code to your question**. If necessary, create a [MCVE]. Note that you should probably use the declaration I gave in my comment above. This entire Q&A is probably unnecessary if you show us your code **in your question**.

Comment: @Rudy This is what happens when you try to answer I'll specified questions. There's no point engaging until the question is clear. Vote to close it and encourage improvement.

Comment: @David: I assume you meant "ill specified". And I didn't answer, just comment. <g>

Comment: Engaging in such detail allows asker to think they've done enough. And wastes opportunity to fix question.

Comment: I apologize for inconvenience, and I modified my question to become more clear.
thanks for your time @RudyVelthuis

Comment: Why the `{` and `}` around code blocks?

Comment: I meant to make editing blocks

Comment: FWIW, if you format your code more consistently, you will spot some errors much easier. Don't use this sloppy kind of formatting. You can use the formatter in the IDE to make your code look better. As I said, you will spot some errors (but not this particular one) much easier. And it makes your code much more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C# declaration you give is obviously flawed: `ref byte buffer` makes no sense. A buffer is not one byte. It should probably be something like `[out] byte[] buffer` (thanks to David Heffernan). Both translate an underlying pointer, but the conversion done on the C# side is different.

Since this seems to be interop code to interface with a plain Windows DLL, I can see what the original must have been: a pointer to bytes, which is best translated as `PByte` in Delphi (but no `var`, that would introduce one level of indirection too many).

So now it should be something like:

```
var
  GetDeviceData: function(h: THandle; buffer: PByte; buffersize: Integer;
    tablename, filename, filter, options: PAnsiChar): Integer stdcall;
```

---

Now you finally updated your code, the error you get is quite obvious:

```
iRetLog := GetDeviceData(iDevID, PByte(myBuffer[0]), buffersize,
  strTableName, strFileName, strFilter, strOptions);
```

That is wrong. You are casting an `AnsiChar` (i.e. `myBuffer[0]`) to a pointer. You need a pointer to the first element of `myBuffer`, so do:

```
iRetLog := GetDeviceData(iDevID, @myBuffer[0], buffersize,
  strTableName, strFileName, strFilter, strOptions); // Note the @
```

---

FWIW, since you seem to be using constant strings, you can just do:

```
iRetLog := GetDeviceData(iDevID, @myBuffer[0], buffersize, 'user', '', '', '');
```

And to make this easier to maintain, don't use literal numbers if you already have a variable that has this number (and must be the exact same size anyway), so do this instead:

```
buffersize := 1024*1024;
SetLength(myBuffer, buffersize);
```

Comment: FWIW, as far as I can tell from what I found online, `GetDeviceData` returns an `Integer`, not an `Int64`. And it is best to declare the first parameter as a `THandle`.

Comment: And I assume this is not your real code. You declare `iRetLog` but later on, you use `iRetLogs`. Don't do that. It makes your code hard to follow and introduces unnecessary errors.

Comment: Next time you post a question, provide more and better formatted code. And, if possible, the *real* code, or a [MCVE]. If you had done that from the start, you would have had an answer *much* earlier.

Comment: `ref byte buffer` can only map to `var buffer: byte` which obviously makes no sense. But asker accepts answer that doesn't match c#. The whole thing is a mess and a complete misfit for this site.

Comment: @David: Yes, `ref byte buffer` only maps to `var buffer: byte`. That was simply a bad translation on the C# side (valid too -- in real life, a pointer is passed -- but unusable). I have seen other translations, and the fact that a buffer of one byte is nonsense, my bet that `buffer: PByte` would work was fine.

Comment: Doesn't match the question though. Now we have an accepted answer that is clearly wrong, given the information in the question. I still don't think you understand the Q&A format here. It isn't personal support. Others will read this.

Comment: It seems to work, so the answer was not really wrong, just different than what the questioner asked.

Comment: I get the format here. But it was clear that his original translation did not work. I know the "correct" translation of the C# code should be `var byte`, but it was obvious that that was wrong. So I answered with something that worked, even if it was not a verbatim translation. Should I rather post code that doesn't work, or simply ignore the question, even if I was almost sure I knew the answer? Is that "the format here"?

Comment: The format is that you answer the question asked. If the question is wrong then it should be fixed. You could do that. But the problem here is now that your accepted answer does not match the question. Feel free to fix it. That arg should be `[out] byte[] buffer` feel free to edit.

Comment: Sorry, but I won't fix the C# declaration. He is not using C# anyway. He merely had a (bad, but existing) C# example. I haven't seen the original, so I won't "fix" it. I can, however, write in my answer that the C# translation is obviously flawed.

Comment: You just don't get it. You think this is personal support.

Comment: @David: I disagree. I think I answered the question.

Comment: You answered it, incorrectly. You claim that `ref byte buffer` maps to a byte array. Clearly wrong. Try to understand that this post is not entirely for the benefit of the asker. It's for every read, now and in the future. Anyway, I cast my vote.

Comment: @David: I did not answer incorrectly, I corrected the error in the question. I do not claim that ref byte buffer maps to a byte array. I claim that it is the wrong translation of the original, a pointer that points to a byte array, and correct it. But I won't "fix" that **in the question**, since that is obviously his code.

Comment: Your edit improves matters. Answer was wrong before.